# Pulse Audio: Meson build failing

Tags: pulseaudio, meson-build

First step I cloned the pulseaudio source from git [ git clone https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pulseaudio/pulseaudio.git ]. Secondly went inside the pulseaudio directory and executed meson build command in order to move to the build directory as stated in README file. But i'm getting this error while excecuting this meson build command.

[image]

```
androidbuild@androidbuild-PC:~/pulse/pulseaudio$ (master) meson build

The Meson build system
Version: 0.45.1
Source dir: /home/androidbuild/pulse/pulseaudio
Build dir: /home/androidbuild/pulse/pulseaudio/build
Build type: native build

meson.build:345:61: ERROR: Expecting eol got eol_cont.
if cc.has_header_symbol('sys/syscall.h', 'SYS_memfd_create') \
                                                             ^  

A full log can be found at /home/androidbuild/pulse/pulseaudio/build/meson-logs/meson-log.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Likely Meson began silently supporting using \ escaped newlines sometime after meson 0.45.1 (the version you have installed). Looking at the gitlab, pulse audio requires meson >= 0.50 anyway, so this *should* have failed already. Since you have 0.45 I'm assuming your on an LTS of some kind (since 0.58 is the latest release), I think Ubuntu 20.04 had 0.45?.

This issue will likely be resolved by updating to a newer meson. You can use pip for this, `pip install --user meson`, or you can probably use a backport repo for your distro (Debian and Ubuntu both provide these in easy to use forms, but all LTS distros have them as some of the dependencies they need will rely on newer build tools)

Comment: yes, the issue is https://github.com/mesonbuild/meson/issues/4720 which should be fixed by https://github.com/mesonbuild/meson/commit/90c9b868b20b11bb089fc5e0c634d5ed76fea0cb in 0.50.0 So, yes, better to follow requirement for pulse audio...

Comment: I'm an upstream dev and i didn't even know we supported \ escaped newlines, lol.